# Border-bottom not showing correctly

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put a border-bottom to the titles on my page, but It seems to underline the whole div instead of just the text. Does anyone whats causing this and how to fix it?

http://jsfiddle.net/1sue4ueg

html

```
<body>
<div id="mainContent">

    <div id="infoContent">
        <a href="#"><img src="./style/logo.svg" class="logo" alt="Drift"></a>
         <canvas resize="true" id="canvas" style="-webkit-user-select: none; touch-action: none; -webkit-user-drag: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);" width="657" height="780" data-paper-scope="1"></canvas>
    </div>

    <div id="projectContent" style="height: auto;">
            <div id="newBlock">
            <div id="aboutBlock">
                           <p>DRIFT is een nieuwe organisatie in het Gentse: een ‘ontwikkelingsplatform’ dat zich volledig richt op de artistieke en zakelijke ontwikkeling van jonge kunstenaars.</p>
            </div>
            <div id="newsBlock">
                <div id="newsHead"><div id="newsTitle" class="blockTitle"><p>NIEUWS</p></div><div class="newsDate">13.12.2015</div> </div><div id="newsContent">PARADIS — Hof van Eede & LOD
Componist<br>Thomas Smetryns koopt online een oude foto van een jonge danseres. Even later valt er een lijvig fotoboek in zijn brievenbus. Een leven in puzzelvorm, zo lijkt het.</div>         </div>

        </div>

        <div id="recentWorkBlock">
                <div id="recentWorkTitle" class="blockTitle">BINNENKORT</div>
                <table>
                    <tbody>

                        <tr class="blockRecentProjet" data-projet="17"><td class="colNameProj"><span class="nameProject">Kein applaus für scheisse</span></td><td class="colNumberProj "><span class="">17.12.2015</span></td></tr>
                        <tr class="blockRecentProjet recentSelectedProject" data-projet="16"><td class="colNameProj"><span class="nameProject">Kokokito</span></td><td class="colNumberProj "><span class="">24.12.2015</span></td></tr>
                        <tr class="blockRecentProjet" data-projet="15"><td class="colNameProj"><span class="nameProject">We don’t speak to be understood</span></td><td class="colNumberProj "><span class="">06.01.2016</span></td></tr>
                        <tr class="blockRecentProjet" data-projet="14"><td class="colNameProj"><span class="nameProject">So you can feel</span></td><td class="colNumberProj "><span class="">22.01.2016</span> </td></tr>
                        <tr class="blockRecentProjet" data-projet="13"><td class="colNameProj"><span class="nameProject">Mystery Magnet</span></td><td class="colNumberProj "><span class="">12.02.2016</span>

                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    </table>
            </div>

<div id="newsBlock">
                <div id="newsHead"><div id="newsTitle" class="blockTitle">DRIFT ORGANISEERT</div><div id="newsContent">
LAB — Vrijplaats voor experiment, ontmoeting en uitwisseling van artiesten voor/tijdens het creatieproces.<br><br>
OP DRIFT — Ad hoc-creatiesessies waarin artistieke talen elkaar kruisen en uitmonden in hogedruktoonmomenten bij In de Ruimte<br><br>
DE AVONDEN — Leessalon in NTGent: hedendaags repertoire en nieuwe stukken worden samen gelezen en bediscussieerd met een groep jonge acteurs, makers, regisseurs en dramaturgen; begeleid door NTGent.<br><br>
WORKSHOPS — Vanaf 2017 organiseert DRIFT workshops rond verschillende inhouden, vormen en disciplines, i.s.m. diverse partnerorganisaties.<br><br>
RESIDENTIES — Ontwikkelingsresidenties vanaf 2017.</div>            </div>

        </div>

                <div id="contactBlock">
                    <div id="contactTitle" class="blockTitle">CONTACT:</div>
                    <div id="listContact">
                        <div class="personnalInfo">
                            <a href="#">
                           <p>Campo Victoria<br>
Fratersplein 7<br>
9000 Gent<br>
Ruth Mariën <br>
+32497186317<br>
info@drift.be

<div id="contactBlock">
                    <div id="contactTitle" class="blockTitle">MAATSCHAPPELIJKE ZETEL</div>
                    <div id="listContact">
                        <div class="personnalInfo"
<p>Kouter 108<br>
9000 Gent<br>
Ondernemingsnummer: 633756230</p>
            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
    </div>
</div></body></html>
```

css

```
body, html
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

body, html, div, p, table, th, tr, td, li, ul, form, img
{
    margin: 0;
}

body
{
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;

    -moz-font-feature-settings: "liga", "kern";
    -moz-font-feature-settings:"liga=1, kern=1";
    -ms-font-feature-settings:"liga", "kern";
    -o-font-feature-settings:"liga", "kern";
    -webkit-font-feature-settings:"liga", "kern";
    font-feature-settings: "liga", "kern";
}

/*
@font-face
{
    font-family: Swiss!important; 
    src: url('AtlasGrotesk-Medium.otf');
}
*/

@font-face {
    font-family: "Swiss";
    src: url("swiss-721-medium-bt.eot");
    src: url("swiss-721-medium-bt.eot#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("swiss-721-medium-bt.woff") format("woff"),
    url("swiss-721-medium-bt.ttf") format("truetype"),
    url("swiss-721-medium-bt.svg") format("svg");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

.logo {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 15px;
  width: 275px;
  height: auto;
}

canvas[resize] {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}


.blockTitle
{
    font-family: Swiss!important; 
    font-size: 8pt;
        line-height: 12pt;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
        height: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.blockTitle > p {
    border-bottom: 3px solid black;
}

#mainContent
{
        position: absolute;
        left: 15px;
        right: 15px;
        top: 0px; /*7px;*/
        /*padding-top:6px;*/
        bottom: 0px;
        overflow: auto;

    /* min-width: 984px;  1024 - 2x20 */
        /*
    margin-left: 10px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        margin-top: 7px;
        */
}

#infoContent
{
    /*width: 624px;*/
    width: 580px;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 42;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    /* background-color: #fff; */
}


#wrapperRight {
    right: 0px;
    cursor: e-resize;
}
#wrapperLeft {
    left: 0px;
    cursor: w-resize;
}

.navArrow {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100px;

    z-index: 99;
}

#projetsList
{
    position: relative;
}

#mainTitles
{
    margin-top: 6px;
    height: 10px;
}

#mainTitles > div
{
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

#mainInfoTitle
{
    /*
    margin-left: 105.7px;
    width: 105.7px; */
    margin-left: 98.3px;
    width: 98.3px;
    height: 10px;
   /* display: inline-block;*/
}

#mainInfoTitle a:visited,
#mainInfoTitle a:active,
#mainInfoTitle a:hover,
#mainInfoTitle a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

#aboutTitle, #overviewTitle
{
    /*width: 105.7px;*/
    width: 98.3px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 10px;
}

#overviewTitle
{
    /*margin-left: 105.7px;*/
    margin-left: 98.3px;

    cursor: pointer;
}

#recentWorkTitle
{
    /*margin-left: 105.7px;*/
    margin-left: 98.3px;
}

#newBlock
{
    margin-top: 3px;
}



/** 5 most recents projects **/

.blockRecentProjet
{
    font-family: Swiss!important; 
    font-size: 8pt;
        line-height:  10pt;
    /*width: 250px;*/
        cursor: pointer;
}

.blockRecentProjet .colNameProj
{
    /*width: 211.4px;*/
    width: 196.6px;
}

.blockRecentProjet.recentSelectedProject .colNumberProj
{
    color: blue;
}


#aboutBlock
{
    font-family: Swiss!important; 
    font-size: 15pt;
    line-height: 16pt;
    text-align: left;
    padding-top: 15px;
}
/*
#aboutBlock .line1 {
    letter-spacing: 0;
}
#aboutBlock .line2 {
    letter-spacing: -0.010em;
}
#aboutBlock .line3 {
    letter-spacing: -0.005em;
}
#aboutBlock .line4 {
    letter-spacing: 0;
}
#aboutBlock .line5 {
    letter-spacing: 0.015em;
}
*/

#aboutBlock .line1 {
    letter-spacing: -0.015em;
}
#aboutBlock .line2 {
    letter-spacing: 0.0em;
}
#aboutBlock .line3 {
    letter-spacing: 0.0em;
}
#aboutBlock .line4 {
    letter-spacing: 0.015em;
}
#aboutBlock .line5 {
    letter-spacing: -0.015em;
}
#aboutBlock .line6 {
    letter-spacing: 0.0em;
}

/** News block style
**/
#newsBlock
{
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-family: Swiss!important; 
    font-size: 15pt;
    line-height: 17pt;
}

#newsBlock .newsDate, #newsBlock #newsTitle
{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 10px;
    line-height: 12pt;
}

#newsBlock #newsTitle
{
    /*width: 95.7px;
    margin-left: 105.7px;*/
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: 98.3px;


}

#newsBlock .newsDate
{
    font-family: Swiss!important; 
    font-size: 8pt;
    /*margin-left: 221.4px;*/
    margin-left: 196.6px;
}

#newsBlock #newsContent
{
    /*margin-top: 2px;*/
    text-align: left;
    font-family: Swiss!important; 
    font-size: 15pt;
    line-height: 17pt;

}

/** list of all last projects **/

#recentWorkBlock
{
    margin-top: 10px;

}

#recentWorkBlock table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    padding: 0;
}

#recentWorkBlock table td,
#recentWorkBlock table tr
{
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 0;
}


#projetsList
{
    margin-top: 2px;
    font-family: Swiss!important; 
    font-size: 8pt;
    line-height:  10pt;

    -webkit-column-count: 2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 2; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 2
}

#projetsList .blockInfoProjet
{
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid; /* Chrome, Safari */
    page-break-inside: avoid;           /* Theoretically FF 20+ */
    break-inside: avoid-column;         /* IE 11 */

}

#projetsList .blockInfoProjet .numProjet
{
    /*width: 85px;*/
    /*margin-left: 115.7px;*/
    margin-left: 108.3px;
    display: inline-block;
}

#projetsList .blockInfoProjet .mainInfoProject
{
    /*width: 95.7px;*/
        width: 88.3px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

#projetsList .blockInfoProjet .contentProj
{
    vertical-align: top;
    /*width: 191.4px;*/
        width: 176.6px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.projectSelected .numProjet
{
    color: blue;
}

.viewedProj
{
  /*  color: #9400D3;*/
}

#projetsList .titleCategory
{
    margin-top: 12pt;
    /*width: 95.7px;*/
    width: 88.3px;
    display: inline-block;
}
/*
#projetsList .charCategory
{
    width: 105.7px;
    display: inline-block;
}
*/

#projetsList .categoryName
{
    display: inline-block;
}


/**
* Right part
**/

#projectContent
{
    vertical-align: top;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: auto;

    z-index: 20;

    top: 0px;
    /*right: 10px;*/
    /*width: 507px;*/
    width: 580px;
    left: 590px;
    height: 100%;
    /* bottom: 40px; */

    display: inline-block;
}

.wrapperPreview
{
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;

    z-index: 30;
}

#infoZoomProject
{
    z-index: 20;

    top: 22px;
    /*bottom: 0px;*/
    position: absolute;
    /*width: 507px;*/
    width: 580px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center top;

    cursor: pointer;
}

#infoZoomProject .previewBigImage,
#tempNewBlock .previewBigImage,
#tempOldBlock .previewBigImage
{
    /*width: 507px;*/
    width: 580px;
    height: auto;
   /* max-height: 100%;*/
    max-width: 100%;
}

#tempNewBlock
{
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center top;

    top: 22px;
    /*width: 507px;*/
    width: 580px;
    position: fixed;
}

#tempOldBlock
{
    z-index: 20;

    top: 22px;
    /*bottom: 0px;*/
    position: absolute;

    /*width: 507px;*/
    width: 580px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center top;

    cursor: auto;   
}

.zoomImageProject
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    overflow: hidden;
}

#infoZoomProject img
{

}


#indexProject, #indexProjectWrapper, #zoomTitleProject
{
    font-family: Swiss!important; 
    font-size: 8pt;
    display: inline-block;
}

#indexProject
{
    color: blue;
}

#indexProjectWrapper
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 4px;
}

#zoomTitleProject
{
  /*  position: fixed;
    bottom: 14px;

    left: 634px;
    right: 15px;
  */
    text-align: center;
    height: 20px;
    /*width: 507px;*/
    width: 580px;
    margin-top: 6px;
}



/**
** zoom on a project
**/
#listPictureProject
{
    display: none;

    position: fixed;
    top : 20px;
    /*width: 507px;*/
    width: 580px;
    /*left: 649px;  634 + 15 */
    left: 605px;
    bottom: 0px;
}

.mainViewDetail
{
    width: 580px;
    height: 100%;
    background-position-x: center;
    background-position-y: top;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.wrapperEvent
{
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
}


#wrapperListProject
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    overflow: hidden;

}

.imageDetailProject
{
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center top;

    width: 100%;
    height: 172px;

    margin-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: center;

    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.imageDetailProject img
{
   /* width: 100%*/
   height: 250px;
   margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrapperDetailBlock
{
    width: 49%;
    display: inline-block;
}

#wrapperListProject .leftDetail
{
    margin-right: 2%;
}


/**
** show list of project previews
**/

#listOverviewProjects
{
    display: none;

    position: fixed;
    top : 0px;

    width: 1160px;
    /*left: 649px;*/
    left: 15px;
    bottom: 0px;

}

#wrapperOverview
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 23px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.colOverview
{
    padding: 0 5px;
    width: 24.1%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

#wrapperOverview .firstCol .previewImageProj
{
    padding-left: 0 !important;
}

#wrapperOverview .lastCol .previewImageProj
{
    padding-right: 0 !important;
}


.blockPreviewOverview
{
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 250px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.previewMargin
{
    margin-right: 7px;
}

.previewImageProj
{
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center top;

    width: 100%;
    /*height: 200px;*/

    cursor: pointer;

    margin-bottom: 20px;
   /* padding: 0 5px;*/
    text-align: center;

    display: inline-block;
}

.previewImageProj img
{
    width: 100%;
}


/**
* contact block
*/

#listContact
{
    width: 100%;

    overflow: overlay;
}

.personnalInfo
{
    vertical-align: top;
    /*width: 201.3px;*/
    width: 400px;
    float: left;
    font-family: Swiss!important; 
    font-size: 15pt;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.personnalInfo a, .personnalInfo a:hover, .personnalInfo a:visited
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.BMEMail
{
    letter-spacing: -0.015em;
}



#contactTitle
{
    margin-top: 10px;
    /*margin-left: 105.7px;
    width: 95.7px;*/
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    margin-left: 98.3px;
    width: 150px;
}

.lineHeadProj
{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: `<p>`'s are block elements meaning that they have a width of 100%. Add this to your CSS  `.blockTitle > p { display: inline-block; }` and it should work

Comment: @SexyTurnip It works! I'll keep that in mind for the future! Thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to you please take `span` replace of `p` tag bcz, `p` tag use for paragraph, if you want work on the same code so modify css

```
.blockTitle > p {
    border-bottom: 3px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`<p>`'s are block elements meaning that they have a width of 100%. Add this to your CSS `.blockTitle > p { display: inline-block; }` and it should work

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1sue4ueg/1/)